# How do I calculate HorizontalScrollView length including its child view

Tags: android-layout

I want to calculate length of horizontal scroll view and I want to identify when user scroll to its end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

we have to use Hscrollview.getMeasuredWidth();

this method have to be used after all child updated in that scrollview completely. 
After UIThread completed its work.